# Laravel 5 - env local debug true no errors shown

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, env, laravel-5

I'm trying to enable the debug for my app but it looks like I don't have any feedback.

The environment is set to local (in the .env file) and if I run

```
php artisan env
```

I get this

```
Current application environment: local
```

The debug config for my local env is set to `true`

```
return [

    'debug' => true,
```

Also if I set in my main config file (app.php inside the config folder) the `debug = true` I still have ho feedback that there is an error in the code.

I only have an empty page if there is an error in the code (as for debug = false)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I have worked around the issue by `chmod -R 777 storage/` on my host machine (Mac OS X). On my guest machine (Ubuntu 14.04) `chmod -R 777 storage/` did not change permissions actually.

Comment: For the record, setting 777 permissions is really dangerous even if you are in a development environment. Avoid unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: do not do this a production server, just set `/storage` to be available to Apache

Answer (score 15):

`php artisan optimize` and if it still does not work delete the file `storage/meta/compiled.php` as mentioned in a [forum topic on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/errors-not-showing-in-laravel-5-app)

I had the same problem and the `artisan` command did the trick.

#### UPDATE

I found out that a nice way to workaround storage folder related issues is to set www-data as its owner.
I'm using two commands:

```
sudo chown $(whoami):www-data . -R
```

and

```
sudo chown www-data: storage -R
```

*From Laravel 5.1 it may be necessary to do this last command on bootstrap folder too.*

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I found that the problem was in the permissions to the storage folder. It's weird because the log file (inside the storage folder) was correctly created, and correctly updated - no permission errors for this file? - so I just chmod -R 777 on storage folder and now I can see the errors. I didn't run the `php artisan optimize` because I just updated composer (that in the end does the same thing as the command above) and I was looking at the folder you mentioned and I actually don't have that folder (that's why I thought about permissions issue). Thanks

Comment: I found out that a nice way to workaround `storage` folder related issues is to set `www-data` as its owner. I'm using two commands, `sudo chown $(whoami):www-data . -R` and `sudo chown www-data: storage -R` (from Laravel 5.1 it may be necessary to do this last command on `bootstrap` folder too).

Answer (score 3):

I had a situation where I had the exact same symptom, some routes were not providing any feedback, just a white page, no error in the log no information at all.

Turns out, I was adding a new middleware, and I forgot to return `$next($request)` from my handle method. This was even more frustrating, because this middleware did not apply to every route, so I assumed that there was an intermittent error that was being thrown but not displayed on these routes.

Answer (score 3):

As Blair said, it may turn out that you put some wrong code in the middleware or in 'Exceptions/Handler.php' e.g. :

`if($e->getStatusCode()===404) { ... }`

instead of

`if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Even on Windows needs to do : `chmod -R 777 storage/`
You can run it with Git Bash;

Answer (score 1):

Also if you just installed lumen make sure you have renamed `.env.example` to `.env` in your main app directory as it won't work if your config is still named environment file is still named `.env.example`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the problem by **un-commenting** the line 
`Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');` in `bootstrap/app.php`.

So that it actually loads it before compiling it and caching it , 
 well running `php artisan optimize` does it for you , if you have Laravel (Not Lumen)

But if you look at their documentation it is commented out by default, i think they might have fixed it by now http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, I had this issue when the error occurred in methods that used `Model::findOrFail($someId)`. Replacing it with `Model::find($someId)` displayed the error log.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers didn't work for you, you may want to check the config files that you might have changed and start debugging from there.

In my case, the above solutions didn't work for me because the root cause of my problem was changing the timezone in config/app.php file (from laravel default UTC I changed it to EST5EDT). For some reason the timezone setting change prevents laravel from logging the errors in storage folder and I am getting blank screen (no whoops! error message). I changed the timezone to America/New_York instead and the error logs are working again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked perfectly was disabling hhvm in the **Homestead.yaml** file, then I did **vagrant reload --provision** and that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***config/app.php*** and if it is like this :

> 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

Then it change to :

> 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),

this.

Comment: This solution change default value, not the reading of ENV file.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem so i have checked handler.php file of exceptions folder where render function that have return value line is commented so page make blank.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{        
    //return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check in
.env file

```
APP_ENV=local

APP_DEBUG=true
```

and also in config/app.php, check for these values

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local'),

'debug' => true,
```