# Laravel errors gone

Tags: laravel, compiler-errors

`enter code here`Hi all my on windows 7(so i don't have any folder permissions) I have can't see Laravel error anymore. It worked fine yesterday. 
why? what's wrong?
Laravel version 5.1 and web server wamp lastest version.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192237/laravel-5-env-local-debug-true-no-errors-shown)

but can't find file -  storage/meta/compiled.php
this command also not working for me - `php artisan optimize`

also debug = true in .env and app.php files

please help

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [installation documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration) you will find the following information:

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.