# Laravel 5. Debug mode

Tags: php, laravel, config, debug-mode

I set debug mode to `true` in config->app and deployed it on the server:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

I have following code in Controller to check the mode:

```
...
$debug = config('app.debug');
var_dump($debug);
$product->save();
```

Result on local machine:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\MK\app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php:45:boolean
>   true

Result on the server:

> bool(false) Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Why isn't debug mode set on server side?

Comment: Check for `APP_DEBUG` and `APP_ENV` values in `.env` files both on the server and local machine. Are they the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This line in your config file, `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)`, may be the cause of your issue.

It is saying; set `debug` to the value defined in my `.env` file, and if there is none then use `true`.

As such it is looking at `APP_DEBUG=false` in your `.env` file, even though you have set the second parameter to true.

Try updating the setting in your `.env` file to true.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the **debug mode** need to be activated! And the `APP_ENV` need to be set to **local**.

Now how to do that! We need to check in multiple places

### .env file

```yaml
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Make sure they are not set twice! You can Uncomment with `# APP_ENV=production` (using `#`).

Too importantly you need to change `APP_ENV` to `local`.

And to check, you can run

```sh
php artisan env
```

You get something like:

[image]

### config/app.php

Next thing to check is `config/app.php`

Know that the `.env` is processed by this file! And that file is where the config is managed!

**Check that the config line is not removed or commented**!
(depending if it's a new install or some already worked  on project)

Depending on what version of Laravel you are using! It may be slightly different!

But the point is to make sure that the .env config is loaded or it will default to **true**!

```php
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true) // second param the default value
```

In our current project! The setting were as bellow:

```php
'debug' => (function_exists('env')) ? env('APP_DEBUG', true) : true,
```

it check if env exists! if yes it use it ! If not it will set the default value directly!

My teammate! Didn't notice that! And he got an error! Becaues somebody before us have changed it as bellow (and was commented):

[image]

The image is added to illustrate how a mistake can be made! Also for navigation clearance!

Bottom line check it out and make sure it's all right! (if all right then just move to the next section)

## Ok all set but not working

Yea to be expected !

### Clear views and cache

Importantly you should know that you may need to clear the cache

Run

```sh
php artisan view:clear
```

and

```sh
php artisan cache:clear
```

After that it should work!

### If not!

#### Files permissions

You may have file system permission problems!

Check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28063794/7668448

## The expected debug view

[image]

Laravel beautiful debug screen ❤️

Answer (score 1):

In your case, just go to your `.env` file and change `"APP_DEBUG=false"` to `"APP_DEBUG=true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the setting into your .env file from

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

to

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```