# Laravel 5.3 not showing errors - gives status code: 500

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-5.3

I am using windows platform(,XAMPP) and laravel errors suddenly stopped displaying on the borwser, However they are getting printed in laravel log file inside the storage folder. It just displays white screen. Any idea where is the issue?

*APP_DEBUG is set to true.

*Permissions to storage folder are all set to full control.

> app.php

```
'name' => 'My Application',

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local'),

'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

'timezone' => 'UTC',

'locale' => 'en',

'fallback_locale' => 'en',

'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),
'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
```

> ENV File

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ZR4gdAiO+agRkOD9mv0cPmrgR55fKZXXZ/F/YN+fUSk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pagebuilder
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

[image: this is the image showing the error page]

Comment: can you share your .env and app/config/app.php

Comment: Try this if it helps you quickly, this question is kinda similar to yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192237/laravel-5-env-local-debug-true-no-errors-shown

Comment: Mihir Bhende [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192237/laravel-5-env-local-debug-true-no-errors-shown) didn't help me

Comment: Have you checked your `php_error.log`?

Comment: @Ross ye it gives following error [Tue May 09 11:48:14.456953 2017] [:error] [pid 5888:tid 1604] [client 127.0.0.1:52915] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler::render() must be an instance of Exception, null given, called in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pagebuilder\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php on line 50 and defined in

Comment: Your error indicates that at some point the exception handler is called to render an empty exception. I don't know why this may have happened unless there's a serialize going on somewhere or you're manually calling it without passing an argument.