# Running Laravel project as localhost causes HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, linux, laravel

everybody. I'm new to Laravel development.

I have a web application developed with Laravel 6. That is developed by others and currently running on the Linux server.
I copied it to my Windows localhost and tried to run using WAMP. But I got HTTP 500 error in `index.php` of the project root when browsing `localhost:8000`.

The error is caused by the following part:

```php
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does it say in the error logs? You can find them in `storage/logs`.

Comment: I tried to find the log message, but no log file is generated.

Comment: Check php error log, and make sure file and folder permissions are set up correctly per the docs.

Comment: That's why I'm posting this question. I don't know why Laravel spits no log message at all.

Comment: There are laravel logs and php logs. Check both. php log location is specified in your php.ini file.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry asking so stupid. I ran the local server with production mode. I turned it to develop mode and fixed it.

Comment: So you've fixed the error or fixed the error messages not showing?

Comment: Running the server in develop mode, no error occurs. Thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your solution with exactly this problem in this link:

[Laravel crash on init with error 500 (no additional info)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289354/laravel-crash-on-init-with-error-500-no-additional-info)

Good luck:)

Comment: My fix is not exactly the same as this one, but those are what I've done for running the local Laravel server and quite well explained. Thus, I check this as "solved".